# notificaciones automàticas xamarin forms

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación multiplataforma en xamarin y necesito enviar notificaciones cuando realizo un insert vía código a la base de datos 
Estoy probando con Firebase, cuando lo hago por la consola del Firebase va perfecto pero no consigo realizar el envió de forma dinámica al insertar contenido.

He probado con esto al insertar los datos pero no me funciona:

```
string json_noti =
Authorization:key=AAAAnu... 
Content-Type:application/json 

{\"to\":\"/topics/noti\",\"notification\":{\"body\": \"test \",\"title\": \"test text\"}}";

StringContent post = new StringContent(json_noti);

var resposta_noti = await client.PostAsync("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",post);

var resultat = resposta_noti.StatusCode;
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Roberen, bienvenido a SOes. Si pudieras traducir tu pregunta, seria bueno, antes que la cierren.

Answer (score 1):

Si desde la consola de Firebase ya puedes enviar las notificaciones solo debes generar una petición con el FCMToken que te genera el dispositivo y posteriormente enviar la notificación.

```
FCMResponse SendNotificacion(string mensaje, string titulo, string token)
    {
        WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        //serverKey - Key from Firebase cloud messaging server  
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", "AIza...."));
        //Sender Id - From firebase project setting  
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", "XXXXX"));
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        var payload = new
        {
            to = token,
            priority = "high",
            content_available = true,
            notification = new
            {
                body = mensaje,
                title = titulo,
                badge = 1,
                sound = "default"
            },
        };

        string postbody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload).ToString();
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postbody);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (dataStreamResponse != null) using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                        {
                            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                            //result.Response = sResponseFromServer;

                            FCMResponse Respuesta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FCMResponse>(sResponseFromServer);
                            return Respuesta;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        return  new FCMResponse();
    }

    public class FCMResponse
    {
        public long multicast_id { get; set; }
        public int success { get; set; }
        public int failure { get; set; }
        public int canonical_ids { get; set; }
        public Result[] results { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string error { get; set; }
    }
```

Te anexo este código que yo utilizo para enviar una notificación unitaria, recuerda cambiar tu KEY y SenderID por los de tu proyecto de Firebase.

Comment: Al probar el código me da el siguiente error: "InvalidRegistration"

Comment: He probado tanto con la server key normal como con la legacy y sale el mismo error.

Comment: El error que comentan lo tuve una vez que estaba truncando por error el token del dispositivo, estas probando en Android o iOS?

Comment: Lo estoy probando en Android.